# Как значение float сделать целочисленным?

Tags: php

Есть у меня переменная, которая получает плавающее значение:

```
$total_price = $order->get_item_total($item);
var_dump($total_price);
```

на выходе показывает: float(18.9). Мне же нужно взять целое.
Так не прокатывает:

```
$total_price = (int)$order->get_item_total($item);
```

Так тоже нет

```
$total_price = $order->get_item_total($item);
$total_price = (int)$total_price;
```

И так нет

```
$total_price = round($order->get_item_total($item));
```

**Upd:**
Проблема решена - после (int) должен быть обязательно пробел!

Comment: Ну попробуйте еще `floor()` или `ceil()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строго говоря, функции округления возвращают также значения вещественного типа. `var_dump()` вам это покажет. Целое значение можете получить так:

```
$int = intval($float); // или
$int = (int) $float;
```

А если "целое" вам нужно только для вывода на страницу или для подстановки в SQL-запрос, то логично сократить этот шаг и сразу воспользоваться `sprintf()` или `PDOStatement::bindValue()` соответственно.

Comment: поясните плиз - с последним точно не знаком

Comment: [документация по bindValue](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), см. параметр data_type